# Add inner shadow in @ViewBag

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on Highcharts and trying to add inner shadow. Please help. Expected output would be as followings:

[image]

Please note the rounded edge of the yellow bars and shadow in the gray bar.

Here is what I have tried:

```
data: [{
    y: @ViewBag.FinalPer
}, {
    y: 100 - @ViewBag.FinalPer,
    color: '#e3e3e3'
}]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by inner shadow? Do you know what would be the expected output? Then we can help you code for that output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and given your prompt time, much appreciated!...I have circle progress bar so that is the Highcharts code, I need inner shadow in grey circle and start & end rounded in yellow progress bar...I have uploaded image for reference.

Comment: The problem is related to Highcharts codes. I have edited your question to include necessary information. Will look into the issue.